# How to find the inverse polynomial in a quotient ring?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$Q[x]$ is the ring and $I=<x^{3}+6x+3>$. I want to find $(2x-5+I)^{-1}$.
The problem, I dont know the technique, how to reduce the degree of the elements in the multiply polynomial, which is greater my creator's degree. 
I'll show you what I mean:

$$(2x-5+I)(ax^{2}+bx+c+I)=1+I$$
I want to find $a,b,c$. Soafter multypling, I get: $$2ax^{3}+(2b-5a)x^{2}+(2c-5a)x-5c+I=1+I$$
Now I want to exchange x^{3} for something that fits the form of dergee 2 and less(using the theorem that there is only one polynomial for each degree lesser then the degree of the ideal). And I don't remember the technique. Can someboyd help me from here showing and explaining how do I find the polynomial' which is $X^{3}$ but with degree lesser then $3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a Bézout's relation between $2x-5$ and $x^3+6x+3$, which is rather straightforward with Euclidean division:
$$x^3+6x+3=\frac18(4x^2+10x+49)(2x-5)+\frac{269}8,$$
whence
\begin{align*}\frac{269}8&=-\frac18(4x^2+10x+49)(2x-5)+x^3+6x+3\\&\equiv-\frac18(4x^2+10x+49)(2x-5)\pmod{x^3+6x+3}\end{align*}so that
$$(2x-5)^{-1}=-\frac1{269}(4x^2+10x+49).$$

Answer (score 1):

In the quotient you have $$x^3=-6x-3.$$

Comment: Can you write more detaily, how do you calculate that ?

Comment: In the quotient by definition $x^3+6x+3=0$.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand the equality ? Why it is equal to $0$? I know it's basic stuff, but we barely talked about it. I mean can you write the algorithm for a general polynomial ?
Or imply it on any other more complicated example with explanation of each step maybe ?

Comment: Take a ring $A$ and an ideal $I$. What does it mean for $x\in A/I$ to be zero? It means $x+I=0+I$, that is $x\in I$ (remember that $x+I=\{x+i: i\in I\}$). In our case $x^3+6x+3\in (x^3+6x+3)$, so it is zero in the quotient.